# How to match n digits and n alphabets in a string in korn shell (ksh)?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

In ksh, I need to validate a string if first 10 characters are numbers and next 5 characters are alphabets in caps.

```
valid_str="1234567890ABCDE"
```

This is how i am doing in sh:

```
if [[ ${valid_str} =~ ^([0-9]{10}[A-Z]{5}) ]]
```

But in ksh it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`` if test `echo $valid_str | grep -P "^[0-9]{10}[A-Z]{5}"` ``